# Dictionary<string, object> prepare using flat list with parent child hierarchy

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, dynamic, hierarchy

I've a flat list of records from SQL stored procedure which has columns **ID, Key, Value, ParentId.**

A key may have any number of child level items or a key may have a direct string value (like a menu). So I defined my dictionary as key and object (object may be a string or again a `Dictionary<string, object>`).

I need to prepare the dictionary of objects because the key values are dynamic from the database and I need to convert it to json.  So `IEnumerable<objects>` is not possible. So I am using `Dictionary<string, object>`.

The problem is it has n levels of hierarchy. So on each recursive call I may need something like yield and return as we do in the Enumerable case but on this Dictionary I need to add the child levels to its immediate parent key.  I'm not sure on how to handle that using Dictionaries.

Here is my code. I think, I am missing something.

```
private Dictionary<string, object> headerFooterValues;
private List<S_Get_HeaderFooter_Result> headerFooterResult = default(List<S_Get_HeaderFooter_Result>);

public bool PrepareTree(List<S_Get_HeaderFooter_Result> headerFooters, Dictionary<string, object> childItems, string parentKey = null)
{
    bool status = false;
    Dictionary<string, object> childKeyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    try
    {
        foreach (S_Get_HeaderFooter_Result item in headerFooters)
        {
            /// always check the whole list
            bool hasChildren = headerFooterResult.Any(row => item.EntityTypeId == row.ParentId);

            /// has children object collection
            if (hasChildren)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentKey))
                {
                    childKeyValuePairs = (Dictionary<string, object>)headerFooterValues[parentKey];
                    childKeyValuePairs.Add(item.Key, new Dictionary<string, object>());
                    headerFooterValues[parentKey] = childKeyValuePairs;
                }
                else
                {
                    headerFooterValues.Add(item.Key, new Dictionary<string, object>());
                }
                status = PrepareTree(headerFooterResult.Where(row => item.EntityTypeId == row.ParentId).ToList(), childKeyValuePairs, item.Key);
            }
            /// has no children
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentKey)) //if parent key exists prepare child dictionary items
            {
                childKeyValuePairs = (Dictionary<string, object>)headerFooterValues[parentKey];
                childKeyValuePairs.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
            else if (!headerFooterValues.ContainsKey(item.Key)) //else prepare parentroot dictionary items
            {
                headerFooterValues.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentKey))
        {
            headerFooterValues[parentKey] = childKeyValuePairs;
        }
        status = true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        status = false;
        throw;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, you´re missing to mention what exactly your problem is. Any error? Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: @HimBromBeere The problem is it has n levels of hierarchy. So on each recursive call I may need something like yield and return as we do in the Enumerable case but on this Dictionary I need to add the child levels to its immediate parent key.  I'm not sure on how to handle that using Dictionaries.

Comment: probably by *not* using a dictionary in the first place, but by creating a class thzat represents a node, where every node in your hieracrhy may or may not have children.

Comment: @HimBromBeere  I need to prepare the dictionary of objects because the key values are dynamic from the database and I need to convert it to json. So IEnumerable is not possible. So I am using Dictionary<string, object>  The json structure matters bcoz it is required in this way....

footer: {}
_address: {
line1: "Otis World Headquarters", 
line2: "1 Carrier Place", state: "Farmington", city: "CT"},
_copyright: "&copy; 1998 - 2018 Otis Elevator Company. All rights reserved."
_links: {}

Comment: You can achieve this also without using a dictionary, JSON can serialize complex data-structures as well. not just dictionaries.